# I am looking for a home for this open-ended question. Can it be in Puzzling?

Tags: discussion

I have a question that is predicated on the **open-ended** tag. I believe that the following fulfils the requirements yet my instincts tell me it will get closed.

In the absence of a sandbox facility on Puzzling, I have the following

**Question**

Will the following question stand? If you think not, what improvements do you suggest?

Here it is:

> Wizards sell magic woo-woo to Muggles.  For example you can buy a
>   spell to rid your house of mice or place a curse on an enemy. Wizards
>   only accept gold (Au) in payment.
>
> A spell is based on a certain amount of woo-woo.  It lasts until you
>   use the spell. You can use the woo-woo towards any spell you like.
>   Wizards measure woo-woo in drogs.
>
> **Example**
>
> You are a Muggle and your shoe has a hole in it. The local cobbler has
>   a very long queue and you need the repair to be done quickly. You
>   visit your neighbourhood wizard.
>
> The wizard states that a spell to repair your shoe will require 10
>   drogs. At today's prices, he is charging 1 puddle of gold per drog
>   of woo-woo.
>
> **Question**
>
> Why does the wizard need gold?
>
> What can you deduce about the availability of woo-woo?

Notes:

1. The question is open-ended because I do not know the best answer but I have ideas about it.
2. All units are arbitrary.

Comment: I'm finding this quite hard to understand because of all the made-up words. Obligatory XKCD reference: https://xkcd.com/483/ :-)

Comment: @randal'thor - Good point. I shall take some time to remedy this and return anon.

Comment: I'm not clear: in the question's universe, is magic real? Or are the magicians fraudsters?

Comment: I don't understand the idea of the puzzle you're suggesting. Is it an enigmatic puzzle with a hidden meaning? Are you literally asking us to analyze the economic situation?

Comment: I'm struggling with the formulation. I'm going to let it sit for a while I mull over it.. Thank you for your comments. Apologies for not being clearer and I'll come back in a day or two.

Comment: "In-world" on your question, wizards require gold to generate woo-woo ?
If so then 1 puddle is probably well over the worth of a drog. And that knowledge would likely be tightly controlled by the wizard union.